# Why the graph coding cannot run inside html?

Tags: php, html, graph

I want to draw a graph bar but I fail to run it inside html. but when I remove the html code, the coding is running well. Can tell me why is this happen? I search for other method. The coding also not running inside the html. Any way to let it run inside html?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Graph</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
# ------- The graph values in the form of associative arrayz
$values=array(
    "Jan" => 5,
    "Feb" => 10,
    "Mar" => 10,


);


$img_width=500;
$img_height=300; 
$margins=20;


# ---- Find the size of graph by substracting the size of borders
$graph_width=$img_width - $margins * 2;
$graph_height=$img_height - $margins * 2; 
$img=imagecreate($img_width,$img_height);


$bar_width=20;
$total_bars=count($values);
$gap= ($graph_width- $total_bars * $bar_width ) / ($total_bars +1);


# -------  Define Colors ----------------
$bar_color=imagecolorallocate($img,0,64,128);
$background_color=imagecolorallocate($img,240,240,255);
$border_color=imagecolorallocate($img,200,200,200);
$line_color=imagecolorallocate($img,220,220,220);

# ------ Create the border around the graph ------

imagefilledrectangle($img,1,1,$img_width-2,$img_height-2,$border_color);
imagefilledrectangle($img,$margins,$margins,$img_width-1-$margins,$img_height-1-$margins,$background_color);


# ------- Max value is required to adjust the scale -------
$max_value=max($values);
$ratio= $graph_height/$max_value;


# -------- Create scale and draw horizontal lines  --------
$horizontal_lines=10;
$horizontal_gap=$graph_height/$horizontal_lines;

for($i=1;$i<=$horizontal_lines;$i++){
    $y=$img_height - $margins - $horizontal_gap * $i ;
    imageline($img,$margins,$y,$img_width-$margins,$y,$line_color);
    $v=intval($horizontal_gap * $i /$ratio);
    imagestring($img,0,5,$y-5,$v,$bar_color);

}


# ----------- Draw the bars here ------
for($i=0;$i< $total_bars; $i++){ 
    # ------ Extract key and value pair from the current pointer position
    list($key,$value)=each($values); 
    $x1= $margins + $gap + $i * ($gap+$bar_width) ;
    $x2= $x1 + $bar_width; 
    $y1=$margins +$graph_height- intval($value * $ratio) ;
    $y2=$img_height-$margins;
    imagestring($img,0,$x1+3,$y1-10,$value,$bar_color);imagestring($img,0,$x1+3,$img_height-15,$key,$bar_color);        
    imagefilledrectangle($img,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$bar_color);
}
header("Content-type:image/png");
imagepng($img);
$_REQUEST['asdfad']=234234;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: This is the output I get when I run this coding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending an image, you must send an image. Not an image in the middle of HTML. If you want to embed the image in HTML, you need to use a normal `img` tag to do this.

If this file is *graph.php* then remove all HTML tags from it and just create another file *something.html* with

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Graph</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="graph.php" alt="Graph" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you give me some example?